# Mapping coordinates list and Rectangles list by binning

Tags: matlab

I have a large MxN array of coordinates and I have a large set of rectangles in a structure Rect.Now i am calculating the density of each of the rectangles buy calculating the area/no of points inside it. In Matlab an inefficent way to handle this would be something like below

```
for ii=1:size(Rect,1)
        ind = X>Rect(ii,1) & X<Rect(ii,3) & Y>Rect(ii,2) & Y<Rect(ii,4);
        Num_of_coord(ii) = sum(ind);
end
```

I want to partition my data in 2D bins, say with N=10. How can i bin my Rect and XY coordinate data into each square ? The idea is i don't have to compare all XY coordinates with all Rectangles. 
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with 'calculate the density of the rectangles'? If your large number of points are distributed evenly, wouldn't `Num_of_Coord` for that rectangle be proportional to its area (which is trivial to calculate)?

Comment: What i mean by density is to map specific coordinates to a specific rectangle .Density is Area of rect/No of coordinates inside the rectangles.

Comment: Now the problem is i have a huge set of rectangles and a large set of coordinates.For each rectangle i want to check which coordinates are inside and do computations.